# Use CloudWatch with VPC Endpoints (PrivateLink)

Tags: amazon-web-services, private, amazon-cloudwatch, endpoint, vpc

I have read the AWS documentation on the connection between the resources of a VPC and CloudWatch but I have not really understood what the objective is.

Does this secure the data transport between the VPC and CloudWatch?
Or is it because the internet is required for communication between one instance of a VPC and CloudWatch?

Is a VPC with an Internet connection required to send data to CloudWatch?

Comment: Can you share link to what you read?

Comment: @Marcin https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-and-interface-VPC.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, to communicate with CloudWatch (CW), for example when using cloudwatch agent, your instance must be able to connect to **CW public endpoint**. For CW, the endpoints are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/cw_region.html).

These are regular HTTP/HTTPS public endpoints, which means that your instance generally requires internet connection. Without it will not be able to reach the internet and the endpoints. However, this requires your instance be in a **public subnet** or use a **NAT gateway**.

Internet access often can be not desired due to enhance security requirements. This is where [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) come into play. They enable resources in private VPC or subnet (i.e. without any internet access) to **connect privately** to the CW, or there services (e.g., S3, Lambda).

> Is a VPC with an Internet connection required to send data to CloudWatch?

Yes, unless you will use VPC interface endpoint in your VPC.